# Button-Images changes size after view finished loading

Tags: ios, iphone, button, interface-builder

I got a problem I don't know how to fix.
I got some buttons which appear in the Interface Builder perfectly fine.
But if I try to run the app the size of two of the buttons will change the size of their image.
That leads to pretty ugly oversized buttons.

I have no idea what could cause that problem, I thought it had something to do with the constraints, but I got no errors or warnings there. And as said before, it's all shown perfectly fine within the Interface Builder.

Has any one of you encountered the same or similar problems and knows a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Autolayout constraint issue. When you run the app in simulator/device, it tries to meet the constraints (in this case, distance of button from view/screen) that were set--even stretching the images/buttons to make sure that it happens.

One solution will be to set constraints for height/width on the buttons. However, this could cause conflicts with other constraints. You'll see a warning indicator on storyboard panel in IB.

Autolayout + IB constraints takes a bit of time to wrap your head around. Don't be afraid to clear them completely and experiment until it works as intended. The reset to suggested constraints option works most of the time, but isn't perfect either.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted everything and added new constrains and that seemed to fix the problem. But its still a designflaw in xCode in my honest oppinion. Why can't he show how the buttons would be shown on the device? Anyways, thanks for your help. I would upvote you if I could.

Comment: I believe autolayout as an imperfect attempt to adapt to different screen sizes and device orientations. I'm cautiously optimistic that with iOS 8 /Xcode 6, we should see dramatic improvements given that layout will be driven by a new sizeClass concept. (until then, remember, don't be afraid to blow away constraints! :)